# grid-template-area, adding extra row gap

Tags: css-grid

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSmZZ.png) I'm trying to create different cards with grid area, column gap is working properly, but row gap is adding extra gap on some elements. And last line structure is not on 1 line.

Here's the HTML

```
    <main>
      <section>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="parent">
            <div class="child">1</div>
            <div class="child">2</div>
            <div class="child">3</div>
            <div class="child">4</div>
            <div class="child">5</div>
            <div class="child">6</div>
            <div class="child">7</div>
            <div class="child">8</div>
            <div class="child">9</div>
            <div class="child">10</div>
            <div class="child">11</div>
            <div class="child">12</div>
            <div class="child">13</div>
            <div class="child">14</div>
            <div class="child">15</div>
            <div class="child">16</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
```

And CSS

```
.parent {
  display: grid;
  gap: 40px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "starry pearl guernica magdalena"
    "storm pearl gogh magdalena"
    "storm kanagawa gogh gypsy"
    "ermin cafe gogh apples"
    "ermin cafe mona swing"
    "ermin arnolini mona swing"
    "boy arnolini sleeping swing";
}

.child {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 310px;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
.child:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: starry;
  height: 200px;
}
.child:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: pearl;
  height: 400px;
}
.child:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: guernica;
  height: 200px;
}
.child:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: magdalena;
  height: 400px;
}
.child:nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: storm;
  height: 400px;
}
.child:nth-child(6) {
  grid-area: kanagawa;
  height: 200px;
}
.child:nth-child(7) {
  grid-area: gogh;
  height: 600px;
}
.child:nth-child(8) {
  grid-area: gypsy;
  height: 200px;
}
.child:nth-child(9) {
  grid-area: ermin;
  height: 600px;
}
.child:nth-child(10) {
  grid-area: cafe;
  height: 400px;
}
.child:nth-child(11) {
  grid-area: mona;
  height: 400px;
}
.child:nth-child(12) {
  grid-area: apples;
  height: 200px;
}
.child:nth-child(13) {
  grid-area: boy;
  height: 200px;
}
.child:nth-child(14) {
  grid-area: arnolini;
  height: 400px;
}
.child:nth-child(15) {
  grid-area: sleeping;
  height: 200px;
}
.child:nth-child(16) {
  grid-area: swing;
  height: 600px;
}
```

I'm new to grid, and wanted to use area because it seemed very easy. I would really appreciate your help with this issue.